How to run scripts in parallel where no nodes remain unused in jenkins pipeline?
Pre-requisite:
1/ I have 4 nodes connected to a label as seen below.
All nodes are connected to Jenkins server, up and running.

2/ My jenkins pipeline is as below where we have three parallel stages i.e., sanitylist1, sanitylist2, sanitylist3

3/ My groovy script is as below
def sanitylist1 = script1.sh, script2.sh, script3.sh //All these are read from string parameter 
def sanitylist2 = script4.sh, script5.sh, script6.sh
def sanitylist3 = script7.sh, script8.sh, script9.sh

 stage('Santiy tests') {
 parallel {

     stage('SanityList1') {

         options {
             timestamps()
             timeout(time: 6, unit: 'HOURS')
         }
         agent {
             node {
                 label 'Autolabel'
                 customWorkspace 'C:/git_repository'
             }
         }
         steps {
             script {
                 for (i in sanitylist1) {
                     echo "running : ${i}"
                     bat "test.bat ${i}" //takes one script from sanitylist1 and replays
                     sleep(10)
                 }
             }

         }
     }

     stage('SanityList2') {

         options {
             timestamps()
             timeout(time: 6, unit: 'HOURS')
         }
         agent {
             node {
                 label 'Autolabel'
                 customWorkspace 'C:/git_repository'
             }
         }
         steps {
             script {
                 for (i in sanitylist2) {
                     echo "running : ${i}"
                     bat "test.bat ${i}" //takes one script from sanitylist1 and replays
                     sleep(10)
                 }
             }

         }
     }

     stage('SanityList3') {

         options {
             timestamps()
             timeout(time: 6, unit: 'HOURS')
         }
         agent {
             node {
                 label 'Autolabel'
                 customWorkspace 'C:/git_repository'
             }
         }
         steps {
             script {
                 for (i in sanitylist3) {
                     echo "running : ${i}"
                     bat "test.bat ${i}" //takes one script from sanitylist1 and replays
                     sleep(10)
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 } //parallel
 } //parallel stage

Requirement:
Since we have 4 nodes connected, we are expecting all 4 nodes to be utilized. But we see only 3 nodes are being used whereas one node is unused.
How do we send the next script from any of the sanitylists variables i.e., sanitylist1 or sanitylist2 or sanitylist3 to the node which is unused to achieve faster replay?
We don't want to create a new stage 'SanityList4' and assign to remaining node.
Requirement is to dynamically assign all nodes to available stages.

What's the meaning of these lists of scripts? Is it to run scripts in sequence on the same agent?

No, we are trying to run scripts on different agents or nodes based on their availability. Not restricted to run in sequence on same agent.

I can't think of a way to do that in a declarative way, but if you are open to a bit of scripting then you can generate parallel stages dynamically from a single list of script names:
def scriptNames = ['script1.sh', ..., 'script9.sh'] // The list of scripts to run
def stages = scriptNames.collectEntries { scriptName -> [
    scriptName,
    {
        node('Autolabel') {
            ws('C:/git_repository') {
                 echo "running : ${scriptName}"
                 bat "test.bat ${scriptName}"
                 sleep(10)
            }
        }
    }
]}
parallel (stages)

Obviously you can add all the other things, like timeouts, timestamps and everything else, put it inside a script block of a declarative pipeline.
